# How to show my app into android market top new free?

Tags: android, google-play

On Android market how can i show my app into top new free apps?
What are the requirements to show it in that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you application interesting, fun, etc.

See this Google IO video on YouTube for what is takes: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twmuBbC_oB8

Comment: Thank you very much! i0m going to see this video !! =) ^_^ thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's a function of total installs since you launched your app. on the market.

Answer (score 1):

That actually depends upon the number of downloads, reviews and popularity. There's no other ways to get on top.